# How to allow user to enter data in the fields in a Table but keep data validation rules on that field hidden?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I am preparing a tracker in MS Excel. The tracker will be used by multiple users across the organization on different PCs. So, I will not have control over what they will do with the excel.

In order to capture correct data, I am using data validation to put rules and validations on different fields in a table, for example, closure date should be more than logging date, etc. And the user can continue entering data in the table and extend the table by creating new rows.

Constraints/Issues:

1. Cannot protect the sheet as then table new rows are not added.
2. Cannot keep the data validation rules open for user to view or edit.
3. Cannot use VBA.

Is there a solution to enable sheet protection along with adding new rows in table to continue the data validation and formatting rules, and also hide the data validation from the user while allowing them to edit the cell?

Comment: So far, I have been able to do this:

1. If I put data validation rules on the same cell where I want user to enter the data, then there is no way to lock and protect those cells while allowing user entry and hiding data validation rules.

2. If we use tables, then we cannot use SPILL, and hence, we cannot do data validation on spilled data.

Only way I have found so far is to not use tables, make a form for exact data entry, copy and fetch data as is from that form to another worksheet and put all data validations there. But this is not a proper solution.

Comment: Also, I cannot use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your scenario and can't reproduce your issue (on Excel 365).

When I protect the sheet enabling only selection of locked and unlocked cells:

- content of unlocked cells can be changed
- validation rules can't be viewed / edited

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for trying. My case involves a table. In the table for a particular column, there is a data validation created. Now I want the user to be able to enter in that column as well as continue creating new rows in the table. In this case, when I protect the sheet, table doesn't extend on new rows.

Comment: Your new comment is substantially different from your original problem in the question "And if I do not lock those cells, they will be able to open the data validation rules for those cells and see the validation for themselves, may be even override them." . It's really difficult to provide a good solution if the target is moving. Please update your question, making sure all relevant details are properly covered.

Comment: Updated the question